# PHP Estoy intentando displayear los errores en la vista

Tags: php, formularios, php7, session, sesiones

tengo mi **form** de registro, el cual pues es un simple form, con los `<php ?>` preparados para **displayear** errores si los hubiese al hacer **submit**

```
<?php session_start(); ?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Registro</title>
    <!-- CSS BOOTSTRAP -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <h2>Registro</h2>
                <form method="POST" action="procesos/insertar_usuario.php">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Nombre</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" name="nombre"  placeholder="Introduce tu nombre">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Apellidos</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="apellidos" name="apellidos" placeholder="Introduce tus apellidos">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Usuario</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usuario" name="usuario" placeholder="Introduce un nombre de usuario">
                    <?php if (isset($_SESSION['error_usuario'])) {
                        echo "<label style='color:red'>El usuario ya existe</label>";
                    } ?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Email</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Introduce tu correo electronico">
                    <?php if (isset($_SESSION['error_email'])) {
                        echo "<label style='color:red'>El email ya existe</label>";
                    } ?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Contraseña</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Introduce una contraseña">
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Registrarse</button>
                </form>


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>






    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Al procesarlo se llama al fichero `insertar_usuario.php`, el cual creara **variables de sesion** por cada error que ocurra, despues comprueba is hay **al menos** un **error** si **no hay errores** se va a **x** sitio pero **si hay errores** nos **reenvia** al formulario con **variables de sesiones cargadas con lso diferentes errores producidos**

**insertar_usuario.php**

```
<?php 

    require_once "../conexion.php";
    require_once "../controllers/usuario.php";

    session_start();    

    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $apellidos = $_POST['apellidos'];
    $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];



    $datos = array(
        $nombre,
        $apellidos,
        $usuario,
        $email,
        $password
    );




    $usuario_controller = new Usuario();


    //Compruebo si el nombreUsuario y el email estan disponibles
    if ($usuario_controller->existeUsuario($datos[2])) {
        $_SESSION['error_usuario'] = true;
    }

    if ($usuario_controller->existeEmail($datos[3])) {
        $_SESSION['error_email'] = true;
    }


    if (isset($_SESSION['error_email']) || isset( $_SESSION['error_usuario'])) {
        //si las sessiones de errores estan alguna llenas manda al registro de nuevo  informando de que hay errores
        header("location: ../register.php");
    }

    else{
        //aqui pasa si esta DISPONIBLE el usuario y el email

        //borro las sesiones de errores

        unset($_SESSION['error_usuario'] );
        unset($_SESSION['error_email'] );


        //si es exitosa la insercion
        if ($usuario_controller->insertar($datos) == 1) {
            header("location:../index.php");
        }
        else{
            echo "Fallo al crear el usuario";

        }
    }







 ?>
```

El **problema** es que **no me borra esas variables de sessiones** y entonces una vez se produce alguna error siempre que accedo a mi `register.php` sale marcado los errores. Fijense que **borro** las sesiones de errores si el insert es defectuoso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes 2 opciones:

Una sería de iniciar en el archivo `insertar_usuario.php` de destruir dichas variables de sesiones:

```
require_once "../conexion.php";
require_once "../controllers/usuario.php";

session_start(); 

unset( $_SESSION['error_usuario'] );
unset( $_SESSION['error_email'] );

....
```

Aquí ya no haría falta en la condición `else` los `unset( ... )`

o

Inicias las variables de errores con `false` y lo compruebas si es `true`:

```
require_once "../conexion.php";
require_once "../controllers/usuario.php";

session_start(); 

$_SESSION['error_usuario'] = false;
$_SESSION['error_email'] = false;

....


if ( $_SESSION['error_email'] === true  || $_SESSION['error_usuario'] === true ) { ... }
```

*(Optaría por la primera solución)*

Comment: Primero de todo gracias @BlackSheep. Si no fuese mucho pedir **como podria  hacer que cuando me me redirigiese de nuevo al form, se auto rellenaran los campos con lo que intento menos con los campos erroneos** , seria tambien con las **sesiones** ?

Comment: Por cierto @BlackSheep, es correcto hacer uso de las **sesiones** para esto que he querido hacer ?

Comment: @josanangel - Si claro... es totalmente legitimo lo que intentas de hacer... y sobre el tema del autorelleno: Podrías meter todos los datos **excepto la contraseña** anteriores en un array y/o lo pasas en una/varias variable de sesiones

Comment: Perfecto, @BlackSheep . En mi `input` de la vista estoy intentando hacer esto una vez me rechace el registro por primera vez el `php` . `<input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" name="nombre"  placeholder="Introduce tu nombre" value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['datos'])){$_SESSION['datos'][1]} ?>">`
Basicamente que me ponga en **value** del **input** en valor de la sesion usuario intentando , pero me sigue enviando vacio la cosa

Comment: Ya encontre porque, me falto poner el `echo`

Comment: @josanangel - Correcto te faltaba el `echo $_SESSION['datos'][1]`... un ejemplo más corto: `... value="<?php echo isset($_SESSION['datos']) ? $_SESSION['datos'][1] : '' ?>">`